# MongoDB Force Update

Tags: mongodb, debezium

I am working on an application that uses [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) to stream changes from MongoDB to a Kafka cluster. tl;dr - debezium tails the mongo oplog for changes to a document and stores the entire doc on kafka as json.

We have a bunch of older, stale data on production that we would still like to persist on Kafka as-is. In order for the documents to be picked up by Debezium they first have to appear in the OpLog. Essentially, we need to `touch` every document in our production mongo replset without changing any of the data on the document. My original thought was to update a field with its current contents:

```
db.contributors.update(
  {},
  {
    $set: {
      "meta.collectionName": "contributors"
    }
  },
  { multi: true}
)
```

However, mongo treats that as a noop:
`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 959, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

My question is: is it possible to force a `$set` update in MongoDB such that the value of `nModified` in the above output is `959` *without* actually modifying any of the fields?

One note: we are using WiredTiger as our backend, so the mongo `touch` command is not available to us.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The Debezium MongoDB connector will do an [initial sync](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/#initial-sync) of the captured collections. So there's no need to "touch" all documents in order to get them streamed into Kafka. Only once that snapshot has been created, the connector will switch over to oplog tailing in order to capture all changes from there onwards.